# Event for select option for mobile

Tags: jquery, html, mobile

I'm trying to bind an event on the options from a select tag on mobile, but the code inside the click event handler doesn't work and I don't know why.

I'm thinking that the click is not the correct event for this specific tag.

```
$('.show-select option').on('click',function() {
    console.log('pressed radio select')
    $(this).siblings().find('option').attr('selected',false)
    showNumber = parseInt($('.show-select option').filter(':selected').val().substr(5));
    if($('.show-select option#all').text() === "All") {
        showNumber = Infinity;
    }
    filterByBreed();
    breederAnimate();
    $('.breeder').not('.active').find('.breeder_breed_desc').each( animateBreeds )
})
```

That console log never runs. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

> > I'm thinking that the click is not the correct event for this specific tag.

Yes ofcourse `click` is not the correct event for dropdown.

You need to use `change` event for drop down not `click`:

```
$('.show-select').on('change',function() {
...............
...............
```